# Code first DbContext with current user filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 website with an code first database and have the following question:

Is it possible to make an instance of MyDbContext class with an additional argument set which will be used for filtering the results of calls to mydbcontext.

I want to use this for restricting the resultset to the current user that is logged in on my asp.net mvc website.

Any directions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why that should be a problem. Something like this should work:

```
public class Northwind : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class FilteredNorthwind : Northwind
{
   public IQueryable<Products> GetFilteredProducts(string userRole)
   {
        return Products.Where(product => product.UserRole == userRole);
   }
}
```

**Update**

To make it impossible for your `MyDbContext` to be abused, you could put all your database code and models into a separate project/assembly. Then make your `DbContext` an `internal` class (instead of `public`), then create a `public` class (`FilteredDbContext`) that wraps your `MyDbContext` and exposes methods that allow you to only grab the data your allowed to see. Then in your main assembly (your web project), you will only be able to use `FilteredDbContext`.

So, for example:

```
internal class Northwind : DbContext // note: internal class
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class FilteredNorthwind // note: does not inherit from `Northwind`
{
   private readonly _dbContext = new Northwind();

   public IQueryable<Products> GetProducts(string userRole)
   {
        return _dbContext.Products.Where(product => product.UserRole == userRole);
   }
}
```

If `Northwind` and `FilteredNorthwind` are in a separate assembly from your web app, you can instantiate only `FilteredNorthwind` from your web app.

**Update 2**

If you use a ViewModel, then your web app can't get back to the list of all products for a category because you extract out only the properties you need (and only the properties the user is allowed to see).

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Products> GetProducts(string userRole)
{
    return _dbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.UserRole == userRole)
        .Select(product => new ProductViewModel
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            Name = product.Name,
            Price = product.Price
        };
}
```

Comment: E.g. suppose i have 3 people belonging to a group. When i ask for the people (which is a dbset) i get only the first, because i'm only allowed to see that one(considering my authorization). But when i'm asking for that persons group object, and query that group for it's people i still will get all three the persons belonging to that group. (Sorry for my bad bad english).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make it impossible to accidentally grab people the current user is not allowed to see. I think I have a solution that might work for that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I believe that when you do a _dbContext.Products.Where(...) call you get a IQueryable<T> in return and not a DbSet<T>/IDbSet<T>

Comment: Still have the same problem. For your northwind database example i can get only my products. But i can get for a product it's category, and then still get all the products for that category, even if i'm not allowed to see those products.

Comment: @Tim See my updated answer for ideas on how you can fix that. We have implemented a similar (not same) solution in our current project as well.

Comment: @Tim, I see what you're getting at. You might need a separate set of model objects (frequently called "view models") that restricts your ability to see anything but the actual data you need to present to the user. So, `GetProducts` would return a `IQueryable<ProductViewModel>` rather than `IQueryable<Product>`.

Comment: Thanx guys, but i was actually hoping for something deep down the drain that would make every sql query to the database including a where statement to restrict the 'products' to the only products i'm allowed to see. I guess i have to add an additional layer (or viewmodel).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a layer above and hide the generated one and create a your own DbContext which derives from the generated MyDbContext. Just a wild guess but it seems logical to me and so you can implement your own argument set and still use the generated one.

Comment: Well i could make an extra layer, but that still will make it possible  to get information i'm not supposed to get. See my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
public interface IUserContext {
    string User { get; set; }
}

public class Database : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorizedDatabase {
    private readonly Database _database;
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public AuthorizedDatabase(Database database, IUserContext userContext) {
        _database = database;
        _userContext = userContext;
    }

    private bool Authorize<TEntity>(TEntity entity) {
        // Some code here to look at the entity and the _userContext and decide if it should be accessible.
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products {
        get {
            return _database.Products.Where(Authorize);
        }
    }    
}
```

This would allow me to cleanly abstract the actual logic around the authorization (and your IUserContext interface can be as simple or complex as required to suite your exact needs.)

To ensure that the user is unable is circumvert this protection using a navigation property (Product.Category.Products, for example.) you might need to turn off lazy loading and explicitly load the required related entities.

Have a look at this post from ADO.NET Team Blog for ideas: [loading related entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)